# How to store the ciphertext generated by the paillier encryption in a pixel?

Tags: encryption, paillier

**Goal:**

I want to implement a paillier algorithm to encrypt images and hide some data reversibly.
This is the paper that proposed this algorithm:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1047320316301808
(this link can be obtained for free on sci-hub: sci-hub.tw)

**Question:**

The paper mentioned that paillier encryption is performed on each pixel, and the data is hidden in the ciphertext, and then the ciphertext is stored in the picture. We all know that the range of the gray value of a pixel is 0-255, but the paillier ciphertext may be 1024bits. If the ciphertext is modulo 256, then a lot of data will be lost and the original image cannot be restored.

My question is how to store the large integer ciphertext generated after encrypting a pixel in the pixel.I think it is impossible to store 1024bits of ciphertext on an 8bits pixel. :)

**What I've tried**

In order to solve this problem, I searched some related papers and some implementations of the algorithm, but none of them solved my problem.

1. In some implementations, a smaller N, 7-8bits, is selected during paillier encryption.Obviously, this can guarantee the normal encryption and decryption of the picture, but there are two problems: first, you cannot hide data in the ciphertext like in the paper; second, due to the characteristics of paillier encryption, N is easily factored, which means this It is not safe.
2. There are also some implementations. After the two-dimensional array of image gray values is encrypted pixel by pixel, it is then decrypted, and the decrypted array is converted into a picture and saved, but the two-dimensional array of ciphertext in the process is not converted into a picture (because pixel value cannot be a large integer), then in practical applications, how should the two-dimensional array with each element be a large integer be stored? If it is stored in text form, how to generate the several encrypted pictures given in the paper.

I am a newbie who loves cryptography and hope to get answers to the question that have plagued me for several days.

Comment: I don't think many people are going to pay money to read the paper you linked to just to help answer your question. You should provide a reference or link to a free resource.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. For fear of infringement, no free link was given, but this link can be obtained for free on sci-hub: https://sci-hub.tw/

Comment: Are you looking for a steganography technique to hide your ciphertext in an image?

Comment: "but the paillier ciphertext may be 1024bits"; actually, it'd be more like 4096 bits if you want to be secure.  A Paillier ciphertext is a value from $0$ to $N^2-1$, where $N$ is a hard-to-factor number.  It is generally accepted that, to get a hard-to-factor number, they should be at least 2048 bits (hence $N^2$ is a 4096 bit number).  If you scale $N^2$ to 1024 bits, that'd mean that $N$ would be a 512 bit number, and there are public services that can factor 512 bit numbers for not that much money.

Comment: Pallier is rate 1/2, so ciphertexts are twice as large as plaintexts (so you cannot encrypt a single pixel into a single other pixel for info theoretic reasons). The [Damgard-Jurik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damg%C3%A5rd%E2%80%93Jurik_cryptosystem) cryptosystem is a generalization of Pallier which is rate 1 - 1/(s+1) for a tunable paramter s. This will still not allow you to stick exactly one plaintext pixel into another pixel (the rate is strictly < 1), but it will let you "get close".